# Solubility of the quintic?

Tags: galois-theory

Over the p-adics, every Galois group is solvable.  Does this imply that the quintic (and higher-order polynomials for that matter) can be solved by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

EDIT: The original place I learned that the p-adic galois groups were solvable was in Milne's Algebraic Number Theory text (Chapter 7, Cor 7.59).

As was pointed out the comments, I should clarify that I meant to ask 2 questions.  Namely, whether the general quintic can be solved by radicals in this context (still no) and whether any given one can be (which I now believe is yes).

Comment: @Jon: You may want to add the reference to the fact that the Galois groups of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are solvable. It follows from the fact that the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is pro-$p$ which, I think, was proved by Koch or Yakovlev in the 60s, and from the recent result of Segal and Nikolov about finite index subgroups of pro-$p$-groups. Is there a simpler proof?

Comment: Yes: the Hilbert ramification groups provide a family of normal subgroups of the decomposition group of a global extension.

Comment: «The quintic can be solved by radicals» can mean either «the general quntic has a solution by radicals» or «the roots of every specific quintic can be constructed using radicals from the field of coefficients». It would probably be best if the question were explicit about which of the two meanins it is about. (The wording suggests to me the second meaning is intended...)

Comment: OK, I am beginning to understand.  Analogously: over the reals every Galois group is solvable, since any polynomial can be factored into factors of degrees 1 and 2.  That *doesn't* mean there is a formula for the zeros in terms of the coefficients of the original polynomial.

Comment: Apart from the general theoretic answers, I hope one answer will address more specifically some explicit formula for the roots in terms of the coeffients ("So what is the solution of the general quinting over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?", Igor Rivin), if this exists at all. As RK pointed out below, this won't be possible without any case distinctions.

Comment: Note, by the way, that every (finite) Galois group over the $p$-adics is not just a solvable group, but a supersolvable group. The groups $A_4$ and $S_4$ are solvable, but not supersolvable, so you won't find any irreducible quartic over a $p$-adic field whose Galois closure has Galois group $A_4$ or $S_4$. At worst it would be $D_4$ (what some write as $D_8$...).

Comment: @Mark Sapir. The absolule Galois group of $\mathbb Q_p$ is not pro-$p$. Eg. it always has a quotient of order $2$: the Galois group of the polynomial $x^2-p$.


Answer (score 18):

Even though every extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is solvable, I don't think one can write down a formula for the solution to a general quintic in terms of radicals; if one could, then the $S_5$-extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(r_1,...,r_5)/\mathbb{Q}_p(e_1,...,e_5)$ would be solvable, where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $r_i$.

Comment: What I meant was that there doesn't exist a formula for the roots of a quintic in terms of the coefficients. Here, the $e_i$ are of course the coefficients.

It is weird, though -- the roots can all be expressed using radical operations, and they only depend on the coefficients, but there isn't a general formula in terms of radicals of the coefficients to spit them out!

Comment: @RK: Yes, it is a nice illustration of the fact that Abel's and Galois' formulations are different. 

Comment: This answer and the comments are enlightening, thanks!

Comment: Nevertheless, Lazard and Dummit give a formula analogous to Cardano's for solving any solvable quintic; see my second answer below.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to solve the quintic over the $p$-adics, two cases naturally arise : $p\neq5$ and $p=5$.

Suppose first that $p\neq5$ and let $f\in\mathbf{Q}_p[T]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$.  Then the extension $K$ obtained by adjoining a root $\alpha$ of $f$ to $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is always contained in $F(\root5\of{F^\times})$, where $F=\mathbf{Q}_p(\root5\of1)$.  So you see immediately that $\alpha$ can be expressed by radicals.

In fact, $f$ can always be taken to be of the form $f=T^5-x$ in the generic case when $K$ is (totally) ramified over $\mathbf{Q}_p$, so if you wish I can claim to have solved the quintic by radicals by just saying that $\alpha=\root5\of x$.

Now let $f\in\mathbf{Q}_5[T]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$.  Then the extension $K$ obtained by adjoining a root $\alpha$ of $f$ to $\mathbf{Q}_5$ is always contained in $F(\root5\of{F^\times})$, where $F=\mathbf{Q}_5(\root4\of{\mathbf{Q}_5^\times})$.  Here again you see that $\alpha$ can be expressed by radicals.

There is nothing special about the prime $5$ or the base field $\mathbf{Q}_p$.  You can replace $5$ by any prime $l$, and $\mathbf{Q}_p$ by any finite extension thereof, and you will get similar results depending on whether $l\neq p$ or $l=p$.

You can even replace $\mathbf{Q}_p$ by a finite extension of $\mathbf{F}_p((\pi))$, provided you replace the "radical" $\root p\of{x}$ (which denotes a root of the binomial $T^p-x$) by its characteristic-$p$ cousin $\wp^{-1}(x)$ (which denotes a root of the trinomial $T^p-T-x$).

Answer (score 7):

The fact is true for every field $K$ of characteristic 0: every finite algebraic extension of $K$ with solvable Galois group is inside an extension obtained by adding radicals (i.e. solutions of equations $x^n=a$). The field is separable since its characteristic is 0. Hilbert's Theorem 90 (see Google) holds over every field of characteristic 0. Therefore if a  finite extension $K'$ of $K$ contains primitive roots of 1 of degree $n$, then any extension $E$ of $K'$ with cyclic Galois group of order $n$ is obtained by adding a root of the equation $x^n=a$ for some $a\in K'$. Now you can apply the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: So what is the solution of the general quinting over $Q_p?$

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks! Is it only pro-solvable then? I thought Franz agreed above that it is pro-$p$. 

Comment: I deleted my comments: these were wrong (because of Kevin's remark). 

Comment: The simplest way to see  that the absolute Galois group $G$ of $k=\mathbf{Q}_p$ is *not* a pro-$p$-group is to remark that $k$ has quadratic extensions (for example $k(\sqrt{p})$) for $p$ odd, and cubic extensions (for example $k(\root3\of2)$) for $p=2$.



  


Comment: At the same time, it *is* true that the most interesting part of $G$ *is* a pro-$p$-group : there is a canonical filtration $V\subset T\subset G$ by closed subgroups in which the quotients $G/T$ and $T/V$ are fully understood,  and the *wild inertia* subgroup $V$ is a pro-$p$-group.

Comment: @Chandan: I asked whether it pro-solvable (reference). 

Comment: $G/T$ and $T/V$ are Abelian? 

Comment: Yes, $G/T$ is *canonically* isomorphic to $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$ and $T/V$ is isomorphic (after you make some choices) to the product over all primes $l\neq p$ of $\mathbf{Z}_l$, so they are both commutative.  To say that $G$ is pro-solvable is just another way of saying that every finite galoisian extension $L|k$ is solvable, which follows from the basic properties of the ramification $(H_i)_{i\in[-1,+\infty}$ on $H=\mathrm{Gal}(L|k)=H_{-1}$

 

Comment: ... namely that $H/H_0$ is canonically a cyclic group, $H_0/H_1$ is cyclic of order prime to $p$, and every other $H_i/H_{i+1}$ (for $i>0$) is an elementary abelian $p$-group.
 



Comment: @Chandan: Thanks! So any finite extension is a composition of two cyclic extensions (which are radical) and an extension of order $p^k$ for some $k$. So my comments that I erased when I got scared by Kevin's comment were almost true! I do not know about Jon Cohen, but I did learn a lot from this discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Dave Dummit's paper "Solving Solvable Quintics" http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X.pdf constructs a sextic out of the coefficients of the quintic which has a rational root if and only if the quintic has a solvable Galois Group.  Although this is stated over $\mathbb{Q}$ I believe that it applies over any field of characteristic 0 or > 5.

Answer (score 4):

Try Lazard (Daniel),
*Solving quintics by radicals*, in *The legacy of Niels Henrik Abel*, 207–225, Springer, Berlin, 2004.

**MR2077574 (2005g:12002)** says : 
Let $F$ be a field of characteristic different from 2 and 5. Let $f$ be a univariate irreducible polynomial of degree 5 over $F$. The polynomial $f$ is said to be solvable by radicals if the Galois group over $F$ of the field generated by all the roots of $f$ is solvable. In the paper the author gives a formula for solving by radicals any polynomial $f$ of degree 5 which is solvable by radicals. The field extension which is generated by the radicals which appear in the result is always minimal, when only one root is produced, as well as when all roots are given. This formula has been implemented in Maple.

*Reviewed by* Jerzy Urbanowicz.

Comment: This paper as well as its Maple implementation can be found on Lazard's home page: http://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~dl/

Comment: Great !  I didn't succeed in locating his homepage, so many thanks for having done so.